# Is there an organization that reviews/approves crypto implementations?

Tags: cryptography

As I understand it, NIST approves crypto *algorithms* but doesn't cover specific implementations. I think I've read about IEEE approving hardware implementations of, e.g. AES, but I can't think of any organization that performs an analogous function for software implementations of crypto algorithms.

Corollary/follow up question: There are many open-source, freely-available crypto libraries; are any of these standardized/approved by any kind of regulatory body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since 1995, NIST has indeed also certified implementations, via the [Cryptographic Module Validation Program (CMVP)](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/index.html) that validates cryptographic modules for adherence to FIPS 140 standards.

OpenSSL is open source and the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module has been validated via this program: [OpenSSL: Important Notes about OpenSSL and FIPS 140-2](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html).

> The OpenSSL FIPS Object Module
>   validation is unique among all FIPS
>   140-2 validations in that the product
>   is "delivered" in source code form,
>   meaning that if you can use it exactly
>   as is and can build it (according to
>   the very specific documented
>   instructions) for your platform, then
>   you can use it as validated
>   cryptography on a "vendor affirmed"
>   basis.

Note that, as they say, "**it's complicated**".  So do check out those links carefully and be prepared for frustrating interactions between the technical and bureaucratic challenges.

Comment: +1. I'm pretty sure MS Windows' CryptoAPI was also certified thusly, and I think also the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace classes in the .NET Framework. But I am not positive...